# Can't see array outside a public class

Tags: c#, arrays

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace arrays_1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public string[] vettore; 

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            vettore = new string[1];
        }

        public void btnImposta_Click()
        {
            ulong dimensione = Convert.ToUInt64(txtIndici.Text); 
            vettore = new string[dimensione];
        }

        public void btnInserisciAggiungi_Click()
        {
            btnInserisciAggiungi.Text = "Aggiungi";
            vettore[] = ["a", "b", "c"]; // CS0246
        }
    }
}
```

I edited the question, but the problem is still there.
I'm trying to see the array named `vettore` created outside and used in 2 buttons. I'm getting [Compiler Error CS0246](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0246?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0246))
as an error, instead. Any type of help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've declared `string[] array1` as *local variable*. Turn it into a *field*

Comment: Or even better, a property, and then make it not an array :)

Comment: *I'm trying to see array1 inside of btnSetAdd_Click, outside of (and created in) btnSetSize_Click* - tell me, why do you think this should work?

Comment: @CaiusJard because it's a public class? I'm not an expert and that's why I'm here.

Comment: I see, (and it's helpful to understand learning developers reason about C#). The public-mess of a class has no influence on the scoping rules that govern accessing variables declared in local contexts like methods. Whatever the class was, it is never possible to access a variable declared inside one method (like setSize) from a peer method (another method at the same scope level) like setAdd. Generally, make every class public and imagine it has no relevance to anything - at some point you'll use something other than public but it'll be rare. If you want variables to be accessible in two..

Comment: ..different sibling {blocks} of code then it will typically have to be declared in the block that encloses both the siblings or some block above it (and by above I mean somewhere up the hierarchy of nesting {} inside other {}, not literally nearer the top of the file). In this case it would be typical to put the variable declaration just inside the class{ block so that code inside either of the method blocks(which are inside the class block) can access it

Comment: @stress Try and learn about scope of your variables before you start changing your code again. Variables inside curly braces {} do not exist outside these curly braces. But there's more to learn.

Comment: @PaulSinnema you said that variables inside curly braces {} do not exist outside these curly braces, however an if statement can see and edit variables outside of its curly braces (it’s not a class, though)

Comment: if(condition)
{
    var variable = 1;
}
variable = 2; <= this variable does not exist anymore because it is out of scope;

Comment: It does exist if you create and initialize it before the curly braces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array1[]` will not exist within the scope of `btnSetAdd_Click()`.

Placing the variable outside of a method will allow you to access it from within other methods in the same class, like so:

```
namespace arrays_1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public string[] array1; // defining a variable scoped to the class

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // initialize array to some valid size upon construction of the class
            array1 = new string[1];
        }

        public void btnSetSize_Click()
        {
            ulong arraySize = Convert.ToUInt64(txtSize.Text); 
            array1 = new string[arraySize]; // now you can resize the array
        }

        public void btnSetAdd_Click()
        {
            btnSet.Text = "Add";
            array1 = ["a", "b", "c"];
        }
    }
}
```

In this context, I would advise you to research some information regarding [variable scopes](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c-sharp/), which is a fundamental piece of knowledge in programming.

Comment: And then read https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/210922/ca1819-properties-should-not-return-arrays-does-this-happen-only-with-arrays

Comment: Good point @CaiusJard. I could have also indicated that using a private scope would work fine for this as well. Without trying to delve into whether what this user is doing is technically a best practice, I wanted to simply answer the initial question.

Comment: Hi, thanks to you both for the tips; I tried applying your solution, but it still returns the same error.

Comment: I don't see any obvious problem with Mike's code; can you update the question (edit it) with your current code?

Comment: @stress Are you really stressed :-) Make an edit to your original question and post your modified code.

Comment: Just noticed I wrote array1[] instead of array, it's working now.

Answer (score 1):

This line is incorrect

`vettore[] = ["a", "b", "c"]; // CS0246`

You don't need the square brackets, just the variable name. Like so;

`vettore = ["a", "b", "c"];`

You only need the brackets when you define an array;

```
public string[] vettore;
public int[] numbers;
```